# Highcharts - Bar Chart Show Text instead of Numerical Values on Y-Axis

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart

I am trying to display a bar chart(with horizontal bars) with Highcharts. For the Y-Axis, I need to display text values based on the range of numerical values. For example, for the below mapping:

```
Range 0-5 - "Ad hoc"
Range 6-10 - "Foundational"
Range 11-15 - "Competitive"
Range 16-20 - "Differentiative"
```

On the Y-axis, instead of numerical values, I want to display the 4 labels "Ad hoc", "Foundational" etc. should be displayed. The working example is found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/riddhithummar/xsvprnmq/14/). The example has predefined values for each label category. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @riddhi thummar, Could you describe more precisely what do you want to achieve? Some visualization would be really helpful. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o91u8cL3/ is a basic chart example with categories.